# $z = f(x, y) \implies z=f(g(x), h(y))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible for every function $z = f(x, y)$ wherein $x$ and $y$ can occur multiple times with any currently known operator, that this function can be rewritten as $z = g(h(x), k(y))$ in which it is true that $h(x)$ and $k(y)$ only occur once in $g$?

for instance: $z = \dfrac{(x^2+4x+2)\log(y-2)}{\sqrt y}$

Can be rewritten as: $z = \dfrac{h(x)+2}{k(y)}$ with $h(x) = x^2+4x$ and $k(y) = \dfrac{\sqrt y}{\log(y-2)}$

Edit: you are not supposed to use $f$ as part of $g$, so you cant say $h(x) = x$, $k(y) =y$, $g(h(x),k(y)) = f(h(x),k(y))$

Comment: How would we rewrite $f(x,y) = x + xy$? Maybe it depends on what "any" operators are allowed.

Comment: If you know a way to isolate the $x$ and $y$ related parts from each other using any **currently known** mathematical operators, I'm happy

Comment: @DavidK Wait, $x+xy$ is doable. How about $x+\frac yx$?

Comment: @grand_chat how do you then isolate the $x$ from the $y$ in $\frac{y}{x}$? What would be your $h(x)$ and $k(y)$?

Comment: @coolcat007 I don't see a way to isolate, so that looks like a counterexample.

Comment: @grand_chat how do you think $x+xy$ is doable?

Comment: @coolcat007 $x+xy=x(1+y)$

Comment: @grand_chat I was trying to come up with an example in a hurry, and I goofed. Your $x+y/x$ looks interesting.

Comment: $z= x+\frac{y}{x} = \int (\frac{d}{d x} (x+ \frac{y}{x})) dx = \int (1+\frac{y}{x^2})dx$ but that would still have the dx

Comment: There is a distinction between a **function** and an **algebraic expression representing a function**.  This question seems to be about the latter, not the former.

Comment: What does "occur only once" even mean?

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the polynomial
$$g(x,y) = (x+y)(x-y)(x+2y).$$
Try all you want, but I don't think you will be able to write it as you want. I don't have a formal proof for that, however.

Comment: Can anyone supply this with a formal proof? Then I'll mark it as answer

Comment: I think $xy(x + y)$ would be an even easier counterexample to prove. I don't have a proof though

Comment: @RobBland Yeah, or (x+y)(x+2y). There must be an easy way to prove it, but I'll be damned if I have any idea how to proceed!

Comment: I have a feeling that this can only be proven if we first get a list of all mathematical operators

Comment: @coolcat007 Also, I think your problem is not well posed. You should try to express it in a more precise way.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud What part is not precise enough? It basically asks if it is always possible to separate all x variables from the y variables on the right hand side of the formula, using any known mathematical construct (I introduced h and k to be able to formally describe the problem unambiguously)

Comment: @coolcat007 Well, *operator* is not well defined (does it mean smooth function? Or continuous? Or just a function without restrictions? Can I define e.g. $f$ to be $0$ at $(0,0)$ and $1$ everywhere else?) Also, what do you mean exactly by *occur only once*?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I clarified the text saying it is for every function f(x,y) meaning any function with only x and y as variables and for the rest only constants. But lets first test if it is true for every polynomial funtion. Then expand to exponential, logarithmic and functions with fractions. In the g, h and k functions however you are free to usa any mathematical notation which is equal to the supposed (polynomial) counter example.

Comment: And your function is expessable with $g(h(x),k(y)) = (h(x) \neq 0  \or k(y) \neq 0)$ where $h(x) = x$ and $k(y) = y$

Comment: @coolcat007 Well, then I am probably allowed to use $h(x) = x$, $k(y) = y$ and $g(h(x),k(y)) = f(h(x),k(y))$, where I use $f$ as "mathematical notation," and the question doesn't make much sense anymore. As I said, you need to be more precise.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I think you misunderstood the question.It is not about finding a function for which it is true, but about finding a $g(h(x),k(y))$ that has the same mathematical value as the $f(x,y)$ that was given. Can you find a g, h and k for $f(x,y)=xy(x+y)$?

Comment: @coolcat007 I did not misunderstand the question. I'm simply stating that nothing prohibits me from using $f$ as a mathematical symbol.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud let me restate the question in my previous comment: what are $h(x)$, $k(y)$, and $g(h(x), k(y))$ for the function $f(x, y) = xy(x+y)$ with the constraints on g specified above?

Comment: @coolcat007 $h(x)=x$, $k(y)=y$, $g = f$.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. Yes, indeed I should state that you should not use f itself inside the formula of g, h and k. According to the current question, your answer would technically be correct, but that was not the purpose of this question. Thumbs up though.

Comment: @coolcat007 Thanks :) I was just making a point, of course. I think you see why I think you should be more precise in the statement.